# Selecting objects within objects - $Error

Tags: powershell

I am an occasional user of PowerShell 5.1 who is getting confused selecting from $Error. I can get the defaults with:

```
$Servers =  "Server1","junk","Server2";
$Results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ErrVar `
     -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -ServiceName Junk `
        | Where-Object {$_.StartType -ne "Disabled"} `
    };
$ErrVar 

[junk] Connecting to remote server Junk failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find 
the computer Junk. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (Junk:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken
Cannot find any service with service name 'Junk'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Junk:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Server2

Cannot find any service with service name 'Junk'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Junk:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Server1
```

I just want to return the PSComputerName and the errormessage. The closest I have managed to get is:

```
$Servers =  "Server1","junk","Server2";
$Results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ErrVar `
     -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -ServiceName Junk `
        | Where-Object {$_.StartType -ne "Disabled"} `
    };
$ErrVar | Select-Object OriginInfo, Exception

OriginInfo     Exception
----------     ---------
               System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server Junk failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. T... 
Server2        System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Cannot find any service with service name 'Junk'.
Server1        System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Cannot find any service with service name 'Junk'.
```

If I use ConvertTo-Json I can see I am dealing with objects within objects.

```
$Servers =  "Server1","junk","Server2";
$Results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ErrVar `
     -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -ServiceName Junk `
        | Where-Object {$_.StartType -ne "Disabled"} `
    };
$ErrVar | Select-Object OriginInfo, Exception | ConvertTo-Json

[
    {
        "OriginInfo":  null,
        "Exception":  {
                          "ErrorCode":  53,
                          "TransportMessage":  "The network path was not found. \u0000",
                          "ErrorRecord":  "Connecting to remote server junk failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer junk. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.",
                          "WasThrownFromThrowStatement":  false,
                          "Message":  "Connecting to remote server junk failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer junk. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.",
                          "Data":  "System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal",
                          "InnerException":  null,
                          "TargetSite":  null,
                          "StackTrace":  null,
                          "HelpLink":  null,
                          "Source":  null,
                          "HResult":  -2146233087
                      }
    },
    {
        "OriginInfo":  {
                           "PSComputerName":  "Server2",
                           "RunspaceID":  "2f2eabc9-4f9b-4681-ad05-c8b72b3d6619",
                           "InstanceID":  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                       },
        "Exception":  {
                          "SerializedRemoteException":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException: Cannot find any service with service name \u0027Junk\u0027.",
                          "SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo":  "System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo",
                          "ErrorRecord":  "Cannot find any service with service name \u0027Junk\u0027.",
                          "WasThrownFromThrowStatement":  false,
                          "Message":  "Cannot find any service with service name \u0027Junk\u0027.",
                          "Data":  "System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal",
                          "InnerException":  null,
                          "TargetSite":  null,
                          "StackTrace":  null,
                          "HelpLink":  null,
                          "Source":  null,
                          "HResult":  -2146233087
                      }
    },
    {
        "OriginInfo":  {
                           "PSComputerName":  "Server1",
                           "RunspaceID":  "f68194c8-40f7-4f35-9b5e-fc6ce385a67d",
                           "InstanceID":  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                       },
        "Exception":  {
                          "SerializedRemoteException":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException: Cannot find any service with service name \u0027Junk\u0027.",
                          "SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo":  "System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo",
                          "ErrorRecord":  "Cannot find any service with service name \u0027Junk\u0027.",
                          "WasThrownFromThrowStatement":  false,
                          "Message":  "Cannot find any service with service name \u0027Junk\u0027.",
                          "Data":  "System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal",
                          "InnerException":  null,
                          "TargetSite":  null,
                          "StackTrace":  null,
                          "HelpLink":  null,
                          "Source":  null,
                          "HResult":  -2146233087
                      }
    }
]
```

I want to select OriginInfo.PSComputerName and Exception.Message but I cannot seem to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `.OriginInfo` property in the generic [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances that result from the inability to even *connect* to a remote computer, but there is a [`.TargetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord.TargetObject) property that contains the specified computer name.<sup>[1]</sup>

You can construct the desired output objects as follows, using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) in combination with [`[pscustomobject]` literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instead of a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call:<sup>[2]</sup>

```bash
$ErrVar | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [pscustomobject] @{ 
      ComputerName = if ($_.OriginInfo) { $_.OriginInfo.PSComputerName } 
                     else               { $_.TargetObject }
      ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message 
    }
  }
```

---

<sup>[1] Once connected, remotely occurring errors are of a type *derived* from `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`, namely [`[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RemotingErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RemotingErrorRecord), which is the one with an [`.OriginInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RemotingErrorRecord.OriginInfo) property.</sup>

<sup>[2] While you *could* use `Select-Object` with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), there's no advantage to doing so here, given that both output-object properties must be calculated, which would make an equivalent `Select-Object` call more verbose.</sup>